# CoreBluetooth Event Backgrounding - no events in iOS 6.0.1 and higher

Tags: core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I work with my ble device in event background mode. So i do not specify any special in info.plist for this.

I have a two troubles here:

1) In iOS 5.1.1 events appear without accessory name.
So when events from ble come when application is in the background i see **The "" accessory would like to open "MyAppName"**

But in

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

i see the name in the *peripheral.name* property and advertisementData also contains key *kCBAdvDataLocalName* @"MyDeviceName"

2) In iOS 6.0.1 and higher the events do not come from background never...

I use ti cc2540 stack, and this is my structs for advertise:

```
// GAP - SCAN RSP data (max size = 31 bytes)
static const uint8 scanRspData[] =
{
  // complete name
  0x05,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_LOCAL_NAME_COMPLETE,
  'O',   
  'b',   
  'd',   
  '2',       
  // connection interval range
  0x05,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_SLAVE_CONN_INTERVAL_RANGE,
  LO_UINT16( DEFAULT_DESIRED_MIN_CONN_INTERVAL ),   // 100ms
  HI_UINT16( DEFAULT_DESIRED_MIN_CONN_INTERVAL ),  
  LO_UINT16( DEFAULT_DESIRED_MAX_CONN_INTERVAL ),   // 1s
  HI_UINT16( DEFAULT_DESIRED_MAX_CONN_INTERVAL ),  

  // Tx power level
  0x02,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_POWER_LEVEL,
  0       // 0dBm  
};


static const uint8 advertData[] = 
{      
  0x02,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS,
  DEFAULT_DISCOVERABLE_MODE | GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS_BREDR_NOT_SUPPORTED,

  // service UUID, to notify central devices what services are included
  // in this peripheral
  0x03,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_16BIT_MORE,      // some of the UUID's, but not all
  LO_UINT16( RPC_SERVICE_UUID ),
  HI_UINT16( RPC_SERVICE_UUID ),
  0x05,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_LOCAL_NAME_COMPLETE,
  'O',   // 'O'
  'b',   // 'b'
  'd',   // 'd' 
  '2' //2
};
```

What's wrong? Help please

Answer (score 4):

Dude you DO need to specify the background mode in your info.plist.....

Under `Required Background Modes`, put in `"App shares data using CoreBluetooth"` or `"App communicates using CoreBluetooth"`... (or both, depending on what your app functionality requires).

Then you'll be able to receive background events.

Comment: I do not specify background mode in my info.plist. And  background events work on iOS5 but don't work on iOS6

Comment: You are completely incorrect and absolutely tripping balls. Those are the iOS 6 background modes..and if u want functionality in the background, then put them in